# using a sequence in sqlj?

Tags: java, oracle, sqlj

I'm new to sqlj and try to insert data with an id generated by a sequence. This is my current code:

```
String pattern = ...;
#sql {INSERT INTO my_table (id, pattern) VALUES (my_seq.nextVal(), :(pattern))};
```

but I keep getting and ORA-02287 Error.
Do I need to do it differently?

Comment: yeah. that did it! Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Note: PL/SQL is based on Ada, not C, and as such you don't need to put parentheses after a function name to invoke it; as a matter of fact, if you DO put parentheses in where they're not wanted you'll get an error (as you've discovered). Best of luck.

Comment: the confusing thing was that I got an error that didn't lead me into thinking that there was a syntactical error.

Comment: Oracle is well known for producing error messages that are, to put it nicely, not obviously helpful. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the parentheses after `nextval`:

```
#sql {INSERT INTO my_table (id, pattern) VALUES (my_seq.nextval, :(pattern))};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not expert on sqlJ, but in the SQL part you should use my_seq.nextVal, with no ()